# Reverse a boolean value?

Tags: java, boolean, shortcut

In Java (or, to be honest, any computer language), to increment an int, you do as so:

```
// Option 1 - efficient
int x = 0;
x++;
// x = 1

// Option 2 - works, but is ugly
int y = 0;
y = y + 1;
// y = 1;
```

How would you do this to a boolean?

```
// Standard way to
// oppose a boolean
boolean isTrue = false;
if(isTrue){
    isTrue = false;
} else if(!isTrue){
    isTrue = true;
}
```

Is there not a shortcut to change a boolean?
For example, if the boolean was `true`, is there a way to change it with just a small shortcut like `x++;`?

Comment: I actually prefer `++/--` *not* being part of a language. They are very useful for "C-like" code, but can also lead to abuse in expressions.

Comment: Why so? You prefer typing `int a; a = a + 1;`?

Comment: Actually `a += 1` (in Java this is also an expression, although if I were designing a language all assignments would only be statements, but I digress).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `!` to flip its value.

```
isTrue = !isTrue;
```

`!` inverts the value of a boolean.

Comment: So this would work: `boolean a = false; a = !a; // a now equals true?`

Comment: @user3422952 Yes, try it. This is about the simplest thing you could test.

Comment: Haha, I'm away from my programming computer - thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3422952 There exists online compilators such as http://ideone.com ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such shortcut in Java.

What you can do is use the [logical complement operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6) to reverse the value

```
!isTrue
```

but you will have to reassign the result.